# How to display Unicode signs (including Polish) in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, unicode

I've got a problem with display of Polish signs in PDF Table of Contents.

In whole document they're emplaced correctly but in Table of Contents I can see only classic Latin letters.

[image]

Demo:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ęśąćż}
\label{sec:first}
\section{ąąąć}
\label{sec:second}
\section{żćź}
\label{sec:third}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know solution for that?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: show a small, complete, failing example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Demo added as edition

Comment: Might be unrelated, with a few exceptions hyperref should be the last package loaded (as it has to mess with a lot of stuff)

Comment: hyperref enables Table of Contents to be displayed in PDF-viewer and it's easier to navigate through the chapters due to direct hyperlinks

Comment: That's not the “table of contents”, but the PDF bookmarks, a very different object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the option `unicode` for hyperref (but it will be the default in the next hyperref version).

I would also prefer babel over the polski package, I'm not quite trusting its catcode settings.

And load hyperref always rather late. inputenc is not needed anymore in a current latex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ęśąćż}
\label{sec:first}
\section{ąąąć}
\label{sec:second}
\section{żćź}
\label{sec:third}
\end{document}
```

[image]